# Vscode Typescript- How to reference types.d.ts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, .d.ts

I downloaded the [screeps typescript starter](https://github.com/screepers/screeps-typescript-starter), and wrote code. Everything worked. Then I tried to put my code in folders (move "src/xx.ts" to "src/prototypes/xx.ts"). VSCode started throwing errors like this:

> Property 'isRemoteRole' does not exist on type 'Creep'.ts(2339)

however the property is declared in types.d.ts. When I try a VScode quick fix it added the property declaration to index.d.ts instead of types.d.ts. What is wrong here?

I tried to explicitly specify a path to the types file in my tsconfig and restarted VSCode, but that doesnt seem to have helped.

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "types": ["src/types.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my types.d.ts was invalid, which is why is wansn't being detected. For some reason the import at the top of types.d.ts caused it to throw an invisible error.

I removed:

```
import { ResourceTask } from "../screeps2/src/_models";
```

and replaced it with:

```
import("c:/Users/me/Desktop/screeps2/src/helper").ResourceTask
```